# I would like to add a unique constraint onto a column. Before running an upgrade, check to see if however that column has duplicate values

Tags: sql

This is fine:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD CONSTRAINT conName UNIQUE (columnName);
```

However, I can't seem to get the following to work:

```sql
DECLARE
    ln_count NUMBER(5) := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt 
INTO
    ln_count
FROM
    tableName
GROUP BY
    columnName
WHERE --change to Having, receive ORA-00905: missing keyword error 
    COUNT(*) > 1;

IF (ln_count >= 0) THEN
--code to stop upgarde script
END IF;
END;
```

Any different way of doing this would also be welcome. However, I am trying to get it to work on both Oracle and PostgreSQL any solution that will solve at least one is already a step forward.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Output: [output of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDHRk.png)
I want to have something similar to the above but have my answer in a variable to be used in order to check if duplicates exists.

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired behavior under different circumstances.  Code that works in both Oracle and Postgres is likely not possible.

Comment: The SELECT statement is not a single value statement. A max() or some other means is needed to make it a single value.

Comment: Only one DBMS per question please. And Bash or Java don't seem to have anything to do with this. I removed the tags for the latter.

Comment: I would like to say thanks to everyone so far and in future for helping, this community is great.

Comment: Despite the written order of the SELECT clauses in SQL, the WHERE clause happens *before* the GROUP BY clause, so you have to use the HAVING clause which happens after.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Your query doesn't say which values are duplicates, so you just get the information that there are duplicates. But if you just tried to add a unique constraint and there are duplicates you get an error, which is the same information "there are duplicates". So what would you gain with the query?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner So I want to run a query as a precheck bash script to see if it has duplicates before allowing the new ALTER TABLE query on live sites

Comment: But the DBMS doesn't allow the ALTER TABLE when there are duplicates, so no harm done. The query that you are about to write already exists in the database and gets executed in the moment you try to add the constraint with ALTER TABLE so to say. Asking the DBMS to tell you there are duplicates in order not to have it tell you there are duplicates a moment later, doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: ... (continuing on @ThorstenKettner's thought) and may be prone to race conditions depending on how transactions are used/set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition on a `group by` is done using the clause `having`.
The query should be

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt 
INTO
    ln_count
FROM
    tableName
GROUP BY
    columnName
HAVING     --- INSTEAD of WHERE
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The where condition is applied before grouping values. You need to group them to know how many records are present in a group. In this case you need to use the `having` clause

Comment: This was my first solution to the problem which persisted in the following error:
`SQL Error [905] [42000]: ORA-00905: missing keyword`

There are multiple threads about this which I still haven't got to working, hence I am here.

Comment: @DianvanDeventer There's likely something different wrong with that version of your query then.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Would you mind to elaborate a bit

Comment: @DianvanDeventer The SQL that Davide wrote above using HAVING is perfectly valid and will not through the "Missing Keyword" error.  If your query throws that error, then there is something else wrong with the way that it is written and we would have to see it to tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you, at first it didn't seem to work but after tweaking it, and as always restarting the database it works. Thanks all